# How does one display part names in the board layout view of Eagle?

Tags: eaglecad

How does one show the part name for a part in the board layout of EAGLE?
In the attached picture I would like to see E2 next to the LED named E2. There are quite a few LEDs on this board and this would be very helpful in laying the board out correctly. This is different from displaying pin names.

Thank you for you help =)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just enable the tNames/bNames and tValues/bValues layers.

[image]
[image]

You can also `smash` the devices, which separates the names and values from the parts.

You can then set position, orientation, font, size, etc. independently.

Comment: If that doesn't work, you'll need to add text to the footprint in the library - one with the text `>NAME` on the `tNames` layer and one with the text `>VALUE` on the `tValues` layer.

Comment: My answer assumes that the parts are okay, since the question was not about how to properly design library parts. But if in doubt just place other standard library components for reference.

Comment: Thank you both. The custom part wasn't named using the convention Tom suggested. And Sekdiy helped confirm a bunch of things were correct in the layers.

Answer (score 1):

Click Attribute symbol (the one that looks like a tag) then click your part.

[image]

This menu pops up. If you're using an existing library it may already have name and value attributes. Just add another NEW attribute with the name/designator that matches the name of the part in the BOM. If the BOM says the part is "Y1" then in your new attribute, under name enter "Y1"